# Есть ли способ пропустить символ не разбивая выражение на группы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python

Например, в строке

```
abc5de
```

найти строку

```
abcde
```

т.е. без `5`, причем так, чтобы результат был в одной группе.

Я знаю, что можно найти 2 группы

```
(abc).(de)
```

а потом соединить их.
Также можно найти всю строку а потом заменить 5 методом `replace` на пустышку. Есть ли способ сразу пропустить символ в строке, используя регулярное выражение?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет это:
    (abc.?de)

Comment: У вас 5 все равно попадет в группу

Comment: в строке "abc5de" нет строки "abcde". Поконкретней , пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя.
Регулярные выражения сами по себе не изменяют текст, они лишь проверяют на соответствие его некому шаблону.

Comment: Так он не хочет его менять, он хочет пропустить символ.

Немного абстрагируясь, можно было бы это представить так:

`(abc(?:.?)de)` - но это не сработает...

Comment: @ua6xh, ТС хочет именно изменить целевую строку, но видимо по религиозным соображениям невозможно считать результатом конкатенацию первой группы со второй.  
ТС указал, что знает как решить задачу с помощью например preg_replace, но ему хочется решить задачу с помощью preg_match. При этом текст без лишней группы должен стать «нулевым» совпадением.

Comment: @ReinRaus, именно